# How do you properly size and fit a gif to Youtube's video player via CSS?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I want to make a theme for Youtube using Stylish. Currently, I'm trying to make replace the spinner that appears while buffering with a gif. However, I can't seem to figure out how to properly adjust the size of the gif. I've gotten pretty close but I can't seem to actually resize the gif or move it all the way to the left.

Here's where I got the HTML and original CSS: https://codepen.io/Webevasion/pen/VQEdRd

Here's the CSS I came up with:

```css
.ytp-spinner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.ytp-spinner-container {
    background: url("url to background here");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    animation: none;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    
}

.ytp-spinner-rotator {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: ytp-spinner-easespin 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
    animation: ytp-spinner-easespin 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.ytp-spinner-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ytp-spinner-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ytp-spinner-left {
    right: 0%;
}

.ytp-spinner-right {
    left: 0%;
}

.ytp-spinner-circle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ddd #ddd transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 6px;
}

.ytp-spinner-left .ytp-spinner-circle {
    left: 0;
    right: 0%;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: ytp-spinner-left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
    animation: ytp-spinner-left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.ytp-spinner-right .ytp-spinner-circle {
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: ytp-right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
    animation: ytp-right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ytp-spinner-linspin {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-linspin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ytp-spinner-easespin {
    12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
    }
    62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
    }
    87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    }
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-easespin {
    12.5% {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    37.5% {
        transform: rotate(405deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(540deg);
    }
    62.5% {
        transform: rotate(675deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(810deg);
    }
    87.5% {
        transform: rotate(945deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1080deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ytp-spinner-left-spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    }
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-left-spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(130deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(130deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ytp-right-spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    }
}

@keyframes ytp-right-spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-130deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(5deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-130deg);
    }
}







@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
.infos {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #000;
}
.infos a {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.infos a:hover {color: #999;}
```

It's currently oversized and only covers half of the gif. Please, how do I make the whole thing show up and fit inside of the video player perfectly. The ratio should be the same as the player already, I just can't figure out how to properly adjust it.

**Major issue I had: you have to utilize the existing CSS and alter it rather than delete it. If you don't overwrite it, it'll persist.**

Comment: Quick tip : add a language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**Positioning was the issue.**

The positioning in the CSS was not optimal. Changing the top, left, and margin properties to 0px and setting the position of the container worked extremely well.

Working CSS:

```css
.ytp-spinner {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lime;
  position: static;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

.ytp-spinner-container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lime;
  background: url("url to background here");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: relative;
  background-position: center;
    background-size: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  animation: none;
}

.ytp-spinner-rotator {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: none;
}

.ytp-spinner-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.ytp-spinner-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.ytp-spinner-left {
  right: 49%
}

.ytp-spinner-right {
  left: 49%
}

.ytp-spinner-circle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 6px
}

.ytp-spinner-left .ytp-spinner-circle {
  left: 0;
  right: -100%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  animation: ytp-spinner-left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.ytp-spinner-right .ytp-spinner-circle {
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  animation: ytp-right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-linspin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-easespin {
  12.5% {
    transform: rotate(135deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(270deg)
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: rotate(405deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(540deg)
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: rotate(675deg)
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(810deg)
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: rotate(945deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1080deg)
  }
}

@keyframes ytp-spinner-left-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(130deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(130deg)
  }
}

@keyframes ytp-right-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-130deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-130deg)
  }
}
```